# Do we need to ban the [free] tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-blacklist

It's not widely used but it's hugely ambiguous as to what its exact meaning is and in all cases the questions were either off-topic or better covered by existing tags that were already applied. I've nuked the nine examples but shall we keep them from coming back?

Comment: But where else would we put Stallman quotes along the lines of "Free as in .... "  ;-)

Comment: Looks like we can kill it.